# Angular toggle button not updating

Tags: angular

I am updating toggle button's state on the basis of api Response.
But when i am changing state of toggle button manually, after 5 seconds it is not detecting changes and not updating the toggle button to the actual state(Same as of api Response).
My code is something like this-

```
  <switch id="switch"  
    [on]="online" 
    (change)="userActionOnline($event)" 
    [disabled]="toggleButtonStatus">
  </switch>
```

Here online is the state which i am getting from the component and it is refreshing in every 5 second

Comment: Are you getting the API response in the `switch` component or the parent component?

Comment: There may be a problem during subscribe of api calling.

Comment: Can you please share the stackblitz?

Comment: I am getting API response in same Component.